# Python: Organization of user-defined exceptions in a complete project

Tags: python, exception

I have some questions about user-defined exceptions in Python and how they should be organized in a complete project.

I have a fairly complex python project with some sub-packages that has the following structure (`__init__.py` omitted):

```
/docs (Documentation)
/apidocs (generated API documentation)
/askindex (my application package)
    /test (Unit tests directory)
        test_utils.py
        ... (more tests)
    /workers (various worker classes)
        communicators.py
        processes.py
        threads.py
        utils.py
    main.py (contains the starting point)
    data_objects.py (various objects used all around the application)
    settings.py (settings of the application)
README.txt
```

I would like to implement my own Exception to use them in the modules of the 'workers' package for specific errors.

Where should I place these exceptions ? I know that I should have my own base exception which subclasses the standard Exception class and subclass it for my other exceptions. Should I create a new 'exceptions' module under 'workers' ? Put exception classes in the module in which they're raised ? In this case, where should I put my base class ? Is my application structure appropriated ?

I am new to exceptions in Python, so please excuse me if the answer is obvious...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general I've found with my own work that when I want a custom type of exception, it's specific to a particular module or package. If it's relevant to a module, I put it just in that module. I haven't yet found a case where it would be neater to have a module or package dedicated to exceptions.

Examples: if I have a `jester` module, with a class `Juggler` in it with a method `juggle` which can raise a `DroppedBall` (cue throwing rotten tomatoes or similar), the `DroppedBall` would be in the `jester` module. Then the `crowd.Person` instances could `try` watching the juggler and `except jester.DroppedBall`.

If I had a package `food`, with various modules in it, `fruit`, `vegetable`, etc. which all have an `eat` method (inherited from `food.Foodstuff`, doubtless), they might be able to raise a `RottenException`, which would naturally belong in the root of the `food` package: `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. I hadn't thought of the __init__.py module. I've never really known what to put inside it except the package docstring and meta. Following your example, would the exception be referenced as food.RottenException ?

Comment: @Marc: yes. One common pattern for big modules is to split them into separate modules and have the package `__init__.py` contain relative imports to join the modules together again (often `from xyz import *`, with xyz defining `__all__`). In this case that's probably not applicable, really. You might potentially want to `import communicators, processes, threads, utils`, though, much as `os` imports `path` so that `import os` implies `import os.path`.

Comment: @Marc: Following that `food` example one step further, the `Foodstuff` class would be defined in `__init__.py`, and `food.fruit` would `import food` and then have `class Tomato(food.Foodstuff)`. So long as you're careful and don't use `from food import Foodstuff`, the circular reference is OK (see [this article on effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question: why does the standard library put all the exceptions in the exceptions package? Is this because there are many of them and they can occur in several different packages ?

Comment: I would expect so, because they do get used all over the place. Another case I just found, the Zope interfaces stuff, has quite a few exceptions, and so has `zope.interface.exceptions`. In that case it's more or less the same as the split-a-large-module-into-a-package case I mentioned, I think, and keeping __init__.py just for tying it in. If you've got a few exceptions and they're not just `class MyException(Exception): pass`-type ones, this may be a good idea.

Comment: I will look at several well known project to see how they do it, thanks for the hint. I validate your answer.

Comment: That's the most satisfying acceptance of an answer I've had yet - it's good discussing such an issue more, it also made me think about how I do it in a one or two projects of mine. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm happy that you are satisfied :-). I am always amazed by this community. There is always someone to discuss your issue and give you nice ideas.